# Abort and restart Jenkins Freestyle Job after n minutes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to kill the current Freestyle Job and restart it if the time between start and now is > n minutes? There are many plugins which help to restart a job after it end with `FAILURE` or `UNSTABLE` but I need the time based abort mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the build in "abort the build if its stuck" option with Deadline parameter to abort the job.